# Book References about Complex Geometry

Tags: book-recommendation, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, mirror-symmetry

I took an introductory course in differential geometry, and now I take an advanced course about mirror symmetry and Calabi-Yau manifolds. I know this is way out of my league but I just want to have a taste.

I would like some good references for books that explain complex geometry and symplectic geometry, and discuss the smooth structure on the moduli space of complex structures.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: A book that I have found to be readable and discusses several topics in this area is "Complex Geometry" by Daniel Huybrechts. For symplectic geometry, "Symplectic Topology by McDuff and Salamon or "Lectures on Symplectic Geometry" by Ana Cannas da Silva are both good introductory texts.

Answer (score 0):

Griffiths and Harris -- Principles of Algebraic Geometry

Huybrechts -- Complex Geometry

Tian -- Canonical metrics in Kähler geometry.

Gabor Szekelyhidi's book --  An Introduction to Extremal Kahler Metrics

Moroianu's Lectures on Kähler geometry.

Werner Ballman's book.